# $C'XC=X\Rightarrow CXC'=X?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

This question is derived from the lorentz transformation.

if $X=diag(1,1,1,-1)$ and $C$ is an invertible matrix, $C'XC=X$. can we conclude that $CXC'=X$ ?

Comment: Yes because $X$ is symmetric: $X'=X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is because $X^2=I$. Suppose that $AXB=X$ for some square matrices $A$ and $B$ (whether $A=B'$ is irrelevant). Then $B$ must be nonsingular. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
AXB=X
&\Rightarrow AX=XB^{-1}\\
&\Rightarrow X(AX)X=X(XB^{-1})X\\
&\Rightarrow XA=B^{-1}X\\
&\Rightarrow BXA=X.
\end{aligned}